# Core 2 Quad or Phenom II?

Tags: cpu, intel-core2, amd-phenom

I'm thinking about building a new machine.  It would be used for video processing, development, etc.  Not gaming.  4 cores seems like a reasonable solution for this.  The question is whether to go with the AMD Phenom II or the Intel Core 2 Quad.  The Core i7 is pricier than I want to go right now due mainly to the motherboard costs.  The AMD and Intel chips seem to be similarly priced and benchmark similarly.  Is there a compelling reason to go with one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take a look at all the linked articles [here](http://a.noma.li/g). That's quite a recent review of some of the higher end chips.

Answer (score 4):

You might also consider the hidden cost of power usage:

- at **load** (if you plan to do folding or something else that loads the cores 100%)
- at **idle** (if it's a typical desktop / server, it is idle the vast majority of the time)

Comment: +1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CPU_power_dissipation   [List of CPU power dissipation]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make from it hackintosh or use [Intel compiler](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-compilers/) buy Intel otherwise buy Phenom II (because it's cheaper a bit).

Answer (score 2):

I'm what you might call an Intel fanboy nowadays.

The Intel chips perform a bit better and the prices are low enough now that there's not much difference compared to AMD.

The main reason however that I prefer Intel is that I've been bitten by bad chipsets in the past when using AMD cpus.

Comment: Same here.  I keep giving AMD a try because I want them to work out, and I keep having stability issues that seem to go back to mobo/chipset (not to mention overheating), so I keep ending up back with Intel.  That said, my AMD powered Sun workstation is awesome!  Apparently it's just not reasonable to build your own AMD system though.

Comment: Overheating is a weak arguement... I build last week a Phenom II 940 system and he never go over 40 degrees on load and 30 on idle.. That said I didn't put 1 millions fans in it, just take and Antec three hundred case with stock fan and it's sufficient.

Comment: AMD makes their own mainstream chipsets now and they're pretty solid. :-)